# "java -Xshare:auto -Des.netsworkaddress.cache.ttl=60..." What is it? Can I unistall it in some way?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, htop

I am reviewing a web service with **Ubuntu 18.04.6** that is reported to load the sites mounted in it so slow. Reviewing the process running with **htop**, I detected that much of the memory is used by various processes with the same instruction:

[image]

Does someone identify what this process is about? Is it something I can uninstall, and how? Or configure it to use less memory?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The user field probably tells the tale:  `elasticse`.  Are you running Elasticsearch on this machine?

Comment: @SottoVoce, you are right, the server is running Elasticsearch, and these processes are related to this. However, it consumes more memory here than other servers with similar configurations. I will investigate if I can change it.